# Google MLKit pose detection not executing onSuccessListener or onFailureListener

Tags: java, android-studio, google-mlkit, pose-detection

I am using MediaMetadataRetriever as well as MLkit to do pose detection on a saved video file. I have attached some of my code here:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> extractPoses() throws FileNotFoundException {
    //public Bitmap extractPoses() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Log.e("DATA SOURCE: ", videoUri.getPath());

        URIPathHelper uph = new URIPathHelper();
        String videoInputPath = uph.getPath(applicationContext, videoUri).toString();
        File vidInputFile = new File(videoInputPath);

        File inputFile = new File(vidInputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to read $inputFile");
        }

        mdr.setDataSource(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> totalVideoPose = new ArrayList<>();


        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Bitmap bmp = mdr.getFrameAtIndex(count);

                InputImage inputImg = InputImage.fromBitmap(bmp, 0);
                
                poseDetector.process(inputImg)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Pose>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Pose pose) {
                                Log.e("POSE DETECT: ", "success");
                                if(!(pose.getAllPoseLandmarks().isEmpty())) {
                                    ArrayList<Float> framePoseMarks = new ArrayList<Float>();
                                    PoseLandmark left_shoulder = pose.getPoseLandmark(PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER);

                                    framePoseMarks.add(left_shoulder.getPosition().x);
                                    framePoseMarks.add(left_shoulder.getPosition().y);



                                    totalVideoPose.add(framePoseMarks);
                                }

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.e("POSE DETECT: ", "pose detect on failure listener");
                            }
                        });

                Log.e("Pose processing: ", "incrementing count");
                count++;



            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                Log.e("POSE DETEC:", "Pose detec ended");
                Log.e("POSE DETEC length: ", String.valueOf(totalVideoPose.size()));

                for (ArrayList<Float> frame: totalVideoPose) {
                    Log.e("POSE DETEC SUBS: ", String.valueOf(frame.size()));
                }
                break;


            }


        }
        return totalVideoPose;
        //return null;
    }
```

I know the bitmaps I am using are correct, as I have displayed them in an ImageView to verify. I am not sure why neither is executing - I dont see the output for `Log.e("POSE DETECT: ", "success");` or for  `Log.e("POSE DETECT: ", "pose detect on failure listener");`. I appreciate any help and I am happy to answer any follow up questions!

Comment: Could you also add the onComplete listener to see if it can be triggered? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)

Comment: Also, could you make sure "poseDetector.process(inputImg)" is executed, e.g. adding a log right before that line to see if that part of code is reached.

Comment: Another thing I can think about is to check logcat to see if there is any info helpful.